# TFS Query Editor: Is there a way to get the underlying WIQL for a given TFS shared query?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

I've been asked to take a bunch of saved TFS Work Items > Shared Queries and reverse engineer them as SSRS reports for more elegant dashboarding.

For all of these I can right-click > Query Editor and it will take me to the Query Editing GUI, which has drop-down list for fields, but I'm not seeing any functionality that allows one to view the underlying WIQL query against the TFS_Warehouse (I'm assuming) database.

**Question**:  Is there a way to get the underlying WIQL for a given TFS Shared Query?

[image]
I've done some searching on my own, and am finding multiple pages related to writing your own, but none where you can get the pre-existing for a shared query.

Comment: You made an incorrect assumption: That WIQL queries the TFS warehouse database. It doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the underlying WIQL you can use <kbd>File</kbd>-<kbd>Save as</kbd>

[image: save-as menu location]

Pick "file" as target option:

[image: save as dialog]

To create a warehouse query use the <kbd>new report</kbd> option in the Team tab in Excel. That will allow you to select a work item query which will be turned into a report.

See:

- https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-generate-work-item-query-for-tfs-api/

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to follow these instructions and it generated an XML file with the query in it.  What seems odd though is the FROM clause only contains 'FROM WorkItems', and looking in the five databases on the server (TFS_Configuration, TFS_CX, TFS_DefaultCollection, TFS_IT, and TFS_Warehouse) I don't see a table or view named WorkItems.   

So .. how can I tell what database this is being executed in, and which object is WorkItems (or if it's an alias defined somewhere else?)

Comment: (Will ask this as a follow-up question if needed..)

Comment: This query executes through the tfs soap api and is not a SQL Server query against the databases.

Comment: Ok, in that case can you point me in a direction of what 'TFS Soap API' is?  As a straight SQL Server developer that doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: You can execute a wiql query by using the REST API, extensive docs are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: Pretty much everything you can do with wiql you should be able to do with sql against the warehouse dB, but the schema is different so you’d have to manually translate wiql to sql against the warehouse schema.